# Not able to locate Freemarker Template In Liferay

Tags: liferay-6, freemarker

I am using Liferay for developing my application and want to use freemarker to develop template.

I was just testing freemarker.
When I deploy my application, it says that Template cannot be found.
I know that template file should be in the src folder.
So I have created helloworld.ftl in docroot.WEB-INF/src folder and in the code I try to access it using the statements

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
Template template = cfg.getTemplate("src/helloworld.ftl");
```

The error is as follows:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template src/helloworld.ftl not found.
```

How should I give my path of the folder?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get ahold of the `PortletContext` for your portlet, and use `getRealPath` to get the actual path to your file:

```
String realPath = portletContext.getRealPath("WEB-INF/src/helloworld.ftl");
Template template = cfg.getTemplate(realPath);
```

Obviously, you'll really want the path to "WEB-INF/src" to which you can append the path to the specific FTL file.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I figured out what the problem was. here I would share it.
I wasn't loading the template before getting the template :)

Comment: Which statement are you using now to load the template before getting it? I'm wondering :)

Comment: Benjamin Seiller:
I has missed including the following statement. Iwas directly trying to access th etemplate instead.
Well here is the line of code I used:
config.setTemplateLoader(new ClassTemplateLoader(getClass(), "/"));

Comment: Thanks for that additional info, might come handy someday